# Toyota corolla 2004 with Kenwood KDC-BT510U problem

Tags: toyota, audio, corolla

I just installed a new radio on my Toyota Corolla 2004. The radio is a Kenwood KDC-BT510U. When I have the Auto 2 on the tuner seek you can go through the frequencies that are stored in memory using the left right buttons. This works fine until I connect the car antenna. With the car antenna connected the right button always goes to the frequency in memory 1 no matter what. The left button cycles through memory frequencies 6 to 3 and then back to 6 skipping 1 and 2. I have changed radio units and even tried another Kenwood model and the problem always persists and always when I connect the antenna. I also tried connecting a different antenna and the problem is there again. So I am assuming that the problem is an interference from one of the other wires connected to the radio that does not work properly when I connect the antenna. Has anyone had a similar problem and can advise me on what to do?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!